# Laravel - Http Request Exit When Throws Error

Tags: laravel

Making a request with `Http::` at laravel.

```
$response = Http::timeout(10)
                 ->retry(3, 1000)
                 ->withToken($token)
                 ->asJson()
                 ->acceptJson()
                 ->baseUrl('blabla.com')
                 ->get('/get');
```

But if 3rd party api returns any error like: 500, 422, 404 that function exits. So rest of my code doesn't work after that all. But actually I need to log all response, even if it returns 404 error, at the rest of the my code.

For example:

```
$response = Http::timeout(10)
                 ->retry(3, 1000)
                 ->withToken($token)
                 ->asJson()
                 ->acceptJson()
                 ->baseUrl('blabla.com')
                 ->get('/get');

$log = (new LogClass)->logRequest($response)
```

But `$log` line never works if `$response` line returns any error.
how to avoid using try catch block and let the code work fine even if the response status code is ( in range of 400 or in range of 500 )

Comment: What you need to do is catch Exceptions. That Http:: (facade) has a lot of nice, extra functions that you can interact with. You can also check for status codes and only if it's 'success' continue with your original code. If the response is unsuccessful, just program what you would like to do

Comment: As suggested in the comments, you may want to check out the [error handling](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client#error-handling) of HTTP Client

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the `Http` client from failing, there is a `throw` parameter on the `retry()` method call.

```
->retry(3, 1000, throw: false)
```

This is also described in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client#error-handling).